# Is there any event that triggers after a session timeout?

Tags: session-timeout, orbeon, xforms

In order to define my own listener, I have disabled the default one using the following property:

```
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.xforms.show-error-dialog"  value="false"/>
```

The Java Script I am using is:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Events.orbeonLoadedEvent.subscribe(function(eventName, eventData) {
                    var test=eventData.details;
                    alert(test);
                    });
```

I want this script to get executed when a session timeout occurs ? How can I execute this ?

Eventually, what I wanto achieve is that I want to display my own error message after a session timeout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no client-side event happening when a session timeout occurs. This is something that happens strictly on the server.

If you are trying to prevent a session timeout, the [session heartbeat](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-state-handling#TOC-Session-heartbeat) feature should go a long way. In a nutshell, as long as users keep a page open, it will ensure that their session doesn't expired on the server.

If you are trying to detect when a session expired, and redirect users to another page, you can do so by registering your own [JavaScript error handler](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/other/redirect-users-error).

Comment: Yea I did create my own listener and provided an alert msg on session  timeout.