# Orbeon session expired handling

Tags: session, orbeon

In ORBEON 4.1 is very strange session expired error handling ... When using DEV mode, than we get plain text error page

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Session has expired. Unable to process incoming request.                                                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-server-submit.xpl                 |  72|  51|executing processor                               |
|oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-xml-submission.xpl                   |  50|  46|executing processor                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException                                                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager     |extractParameters             |XFormsStateManager.java       | 403|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer       |doIt                          |XFormsServer.java             | 152|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer       |start                         |XFormsServer.java             | 100|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        | 617|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException          |wrapException                 |ValidationException.java      | 126|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        | 619|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeChildren               |PipelineProcessor.java        | 679|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|start                         |PipelineProcessor.java        | 614|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteCh|start                         |ConcreteChooseProcessor.java  | 248|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        | 617|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeChildren               |PipelineProcessor.java        | 679|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|start                         |PipelineProcessor.java        | 614|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        | 617|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeChildren               |PipelineProcessor.java        | 679|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|start                         |PipelineProcessor.java        | 614|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|getInput                      |PipelineProcessor.java        | 140|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|readImpl                      |PipelineProcessor.java        |  83|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$T|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 258|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 404|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteCh|readImpl                      |ConcreteChooseProcessor.java  | 127|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$T|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 258|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 404|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        |  92|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService             |service                       |ProcessorService.scala        |  40|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$servi|apply$mcV$sp                  |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  74|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$servi|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$servi|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$                    |withRootException             |ScalaUtils.scala              | 118|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet               |service                       |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet                     |service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 820|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$Servle|run                           |StubSecurityHelper.java       | 227|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper       |invokeServlet                 |StubSecurityHelper.java       | 125|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl          |execute                       |ServletStubImpl.java          | 300|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl          |execute                       |ServletStubImpl.java          | 183|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$Serv|doIt                          |WebAppServletContext.java     |3683|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$Serv|run                           |WebAppServletContext.java     |3650|
|weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject|doAs                          |AuthenticatedSubject.java     | 321|
|weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager          |runAs                         |SecurityManager.java          | 121|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext     |securedExecute                |WebAppServletContext.java     |2268|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext     |execute                       |WebAppServletContext.java     |2174|
|weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl       |run                           |ServletRequestImpl.java       |1446|
|weblogic.work.ExecuteThread                        |execute                       |ExecuteThread.java            | 201|
|weblogic.work.ExecuteThread                        |run                           |ExecuteThread.java            | 173|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It should be OK (its in DEV mode by the way ...), but if we switch to PROD mode, than user got plain Error occurred error without error details. Session timeout is very common error and we need show to user user friendly page with instruction what to do. Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any event that triggers after a session timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188379/is-there-any-event-that-triggers-after-a-session-timeout)

Comment: Of course, just let us know by posting a comment here if the answer in the other question I referenced doesn't resolve your problem.

Comment: No, it is different problem. Trigger for session timeout in AJAX should be nice, but this issue is about session timeout in base pages where is an problem in org.orbeon.oxf.webap.ProcessorService.scala at serviceStaticError - if response is commited, than stack from this issue is printed when in DEV mode and plain `An error has occurred while processing the request.` in PROD mode. We got this error for session timeout too and there is no way to change error page for it ...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the use case. You're saying a session expires, and you'd like to redirect users to another page. If it happens during an Ajax request, then you can do the redirect in a JavaScript handler on `errorEvent`. Are the session expires in another situation? I.e. not on Ajax request? What situation is that?